# TableAdapter Update function return

Tags: vb.net, function, sql-update, tableadapter

While programming, I notice that the tableadapter's update is a function and returns an integer.
I'm wondering, what is the meaning of the return value?

I'm programming in VB Express 2010

Comment: what exactly the function name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning the number of rows affected by the update. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx